# Does AWS RDS (non Aurora ones) uses some customized version of the original databases?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Does AWS customize the databases (eg postgres/mysql) for using it in RDS (non Aurora) or is it the same open source ones without any modifications?

I want to understand if there can be any subtle compatibility issues/bugs between the open source versions of the databases and the RDS managed instances of the same database versions.

Comment: Yes, for plain old RDS you're working with specific versions of the unmodified database types (MySQL, MariaDB, MSSQL, etc).

Comment: @Norman Is it certain that these are vanila databases? If yes, how would IAM authentication work without any modifications to mysql for example?